# Javascript horizontal scrolling text, change color

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I need to change color of the text in this script:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
var bannerID=0
function text(msg,ctrlwidth) {
msg = " --- "+msg
newmsg = msg
while (newmsg.length < ctrlwidth) {
newmsg += msg
}
document.write ('<FORM NAME="Scrolltext">');
document.write ('<CENTER><INPUT NAME="text" VALUE= "'+newmsg+'" SIZE= '+ctrlwidth+' ></CENTER>');
document.write ('</FORM>');
var bannerID = null
rollmsg()
}
function rollmsg() {
NowMsg = document.Scrolltext.text.value
NowMsg = NowMsg.substring(1,NowMsg.length)+NowMsg.substring(0,1)
document.Scrolltext.text.value = NowMsg
bannerID = setTimeout("rollmsg()",100)//change the number 100 to represent the speed of the scroll. The larger the number the slower it moves
}
// -->
</script>


<script>
<!--
msg = " TEXT GOES HERE"
ctrlwidth = "100" //change this number to the length you would like the message box to be
text(msg,ctrlwidth);
// -->
</script>
```

The current text color is black and it should be white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `style` property, try the following code:

```
function rollmsg() {
  NowMsg = document.Scrolltext.text.value;
  NowMsg = NowMsg.substring(1,NowMsg.length)+NowMsg.substring(0,1);
  document.Scrolltext.text.value = NowMsg;
  document.Scrolltext.text.style.color ="white"; //use the style proprety here
  bannerID = setTimeout("rollmsg()",100)//change the number 100 to represent the speed of the  scroll. The larger the number the slower it moves
}
```

Comment: Well glad it helps, just remember that you have to use `.style`to access an element style.

Comment: Will do. Do you by any chance know how to make it scroll from left to right? The opposite of its current direction of scroll

Comment: Well I think rhe easiest way is to use `<marquee>` [take a look at the exemple here](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/scrolling_text.cfm).

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should use CSS for that.

```
body{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

[What is CSS? | W3C](http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss)

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
   var result = NowMsg.fontcolor("white");
```

Comment: Where do I need to place this?

Comment: Add it below the code
document.Scrolltext.text.value = NowMsg
NowMsg.fontcolor("white");